# Docker failing to see updated fixtures CSV in rspec test directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

This one is quite strange.

I am running a very typical Docker container that holds a Rails API. Inside this API, I have an endpoint which takes an upload of a CSV and does some things and stuff.

Here is the exact flow:

```
vim spec/fixtuers/bid_update.csv
# fill it with some data
# now we call the spec that uses this fixture
docker-compose run --rm web bundle exec rspec spec/requests/bids_spec.rb
# and now the csv is loaded and I can see it as plaintext
```

However, after creating this, I decided to change the content of the CSV. So I do this, adding a column and respective value to it for each piece.

Now, however, when we run our spec again after saving this it has the old version of the CSV. The one originally used at the breakpoint in the spec.

`cat`'ing out the CSV shows it clearly should have the new content.

Restarting the VM does nothing. The only solution I've found is to `docker-machine rm dev` and build a new machine (my main one for this is called dev).

I am entirely perplexed as to what could cause this or a simple means to fix it (building with all those images takes a while).

Ideas? Inform me I'm an idiot and I just had to press 0 for an operator and they would have fixed it?

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be an issue with how virtualbox shares folders with your environment. More information here https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/351#issuecomment-1339640

Comment: After switching to docker for mac this is no longer an issue since it doesn't use VirtualBox.